# Microsoft IIS URL Rewrite - regex

Tags: regex, iis, coldfusion, url-rewriting

Im currently working with my IIS Server and ive installed the IIS rewrite module.

I currently have a rule on it which allows for all my coldfusion templates to be parsed really easily.

it generates the following pattern

```
^([^/]+)/?$
```

which covers any request for any template on the following page

```
index.cfm?action={R:1}
```

This rule simply parses any request into my website and makes it go directly to my index.cfm page.

What Im trying to understand is how to get the following.

1. `^/css/` - then any script or sub folder to process like any other page request
2. `^/js/` - then process any js file as it is stored on my server
3. `^/assets/` - process any file in this folder as a normal file.

Ive never used this module before but im struggling to find out how to treat normal files like js and css as they are and in their respective directories.

I have no problem in writing the rules so each is prefixed with the folder names but cant for the life of me work out where to get any information on this from.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you specify a rule **before** the one that catches everything, you should be able to use the `stopProcessing` attribute to prevent the module from doing anything with the request. There's no need to specify an action. For example:

```
<rule name="CSS files" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="^/css/" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is for all static files

```
<rule name="Static Files" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(.*)$" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
    <add input="{SCRIPT_NAME}" pattern="\.(bmp|gif|jpe?g|png|css|js|txt|pdf|doc|xls)$" ignoreCase="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="None" />
</rule>
```

Update:
I am sorry, I haven't notice you have asked for folder. But I keep in answer in case other people like to know about it.

Comment: I believe the above condition pattern should IgnoreCase, since we want to skip a BMP file regardless of the case of the extension.

Comment: I agree with above. Ignore case true for assets. Other than that, this is a great rule. Thanks.